# Godot окно "Theme" изменило размер

Tags: godot

Сделал новую тему, указал большой размер шрифта и что я вижу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

окно просто отказывается сужаться даже тогда, когда я меняю макет на дефолтный

как это исправить?

Comment: Сбросить все настройки пробовали? Возможно, тут поможет переустановка. Штука с темами коварная во многих приложениях

Comment: я уже нашёл решение. но всё же оно не очень приятное. для этого нужно сначала закрыть окно темы, переключившись на консоль или ещё что-то, сверху в тулбаре нажать "Редактор", дальше нажать "Макет редактора" и выбрать "По умолчанию", после чего открыть Godot в оконном режиме, после чего открыть в полный экран. я не знаю, как я догадался сделать эти действия :)

Comment: Ух костыли)) Но раз решили, то можете сами ответить за свой вопрос, чтобы другие видели ответ, если столкнутся со схожей проблемой.

Comment: кпец рял ща отвечу

Answer (score 0):

я уже нашёл решение. но всё же оно не очень приятное. для этого нужно сначала закрыть окно темы, переключившись на консоль или ещё что-то, сверху в тулбаре нажать "Редактор", дальше нажать "Макет редактора" и выбрать "По умолчанию", после чего открыть Godot в оконном режиме, после чего открыть в полный экран. я не знаю, как я догадался сделать эти действия :)